# Error with oleacc.dll Call - Access Denied Error 80020009

Tags: c++, dll, call, functional-testing, autoit

I'm writing a Functional Test script for a client based application from a vendor which uses `Internet Explorer_Server` embedded controls.  I'm having a difficult time trying to get the object so that I can read it's HTML and verify information.  I'm able to get the handle for the internal control and I'm trying to use oleacc.dll's ObjectFromLresult function to get the object.  Alas, it's failing due to 80020009 Access is Denied.

I'm hoping to get this working, or at least know exactly why it's failing.  Here's the code:

```
DllCall("ole32.dll", "long", "CoInitialize", "ptr", 0)

Local $typUUID = DllStructCreate("int;short;short;byte[8]")
DllStructSetData($typUUID, 1, 0x626FC520)
DllStructSetData($typUUID, 2, 0xA41E)
DllStructSetData($typUUID, 3, 0x11CF)
DllStructSetData($typUUID, 4, 0xA7, 1)
DllStructSetData($typUUID, 4, 0x31, 2)
DllStructSetData($typUUID, 4, 0x0, 3)
DllStructSetData($typUUID, 4, 0xA0, 4)
DllStructSetData($typUUID, 4, 0xC9, 5)
DllStructSetData($typUUID, 4, 0x8, 6)
DllStructSetData($typUUID, 4, 0x26, 7)
DllStructSetData($typUUID, 4, 0x37, 8)
If IsDllStruct($typUUID) Then
    ConsoleWrite("$typUUID is a DLL Struct." & @LF)
Else
    ConsoleWrite("$typUUID is NOT a DLL Struct." & @LF)
EndIf

$lResult = 49263


Local $aRet = DllCall("oleacc.dll", _
    "long", "ObjectFromLresult", _
    "lresult", $lResult, _
    "struct*", $typUUID, _
    "wparam", 0, _
    "idispatch*", 0)
If @error Then Return SetError(3, @error, 0)


If IsObj($aRet[4]) Then
    ConsoleWrite("$aRet[4] is an object!" & @lf)
    Local $oIE = $aRet[4] .Script()
    ; $oIE is now a valid IDispatch object
    Return $oIE.Document.parentwindow
Else
    Return SetError(1, $aRet[0], 0)
EndIf
```

Some notes:

*The IsDllStruct check is successfun and reports that $typUUID is a Dll Struct.

*The $lResult is the handle to the Internet Explorer_Server internal/embedded control.

*The the data in array position $aRet[4] is an object.

*There is no error until `Return $oIE.Document.parentwindow`

Answer (score -2):

Try to use

```
#include <IE.au3>

$oIE = _IEAttach("[REGEXPTITLE:ICQ; INSTANCE:2]", "embedded", 3)
```

This example shows how to attach to ICQ client that is using embedded IE control.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that you are aiming the right window?
use _IEErrorHandlerRegister to see why is it failing.

Comment: Yes, I am, and yes I have and it's the error in the title of the question.

Comment: Try to set IE security settings to "low". There is also an option to enable/disable DOM scripting in IE.
Also, if you aren't using IE, try to downgrade it.

Comment: Also, if you got the object as you have written in your question, try to use it with _ie functions instead of fiddling with it youself ;)

Comment: The _IE functions don't work.  They produce errors, which again is why I have to accomplish my goal in this way.  My question is nothing to do with autoit coding syntax and everything to do with proper DLL calls.  It's only tagged with AutoIt because that's the IDE I'm using.